# WPF Toggle button with animated content

Tags: wpf, image, templates, togglebutton

I wanted to create a toggle button, which contains two gray cog wheels when it's unchecked and two red rotating cogs when it's pushed. I have created a template with triggers checking *IsChecked* property and setting button's content accordingly.

It seems to be working just fine, but as soon as I add two buttons to the page, first one seems to be blank (with no images). It looks like only one button can be turned on or off at the same time.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="CogwheelButton.Border.Color" Color="Transparent"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="CogwheelButton.Background.Color" Color="Transparent"/>

<Style x:Key="CogwheelButton" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource CogwheelButton.Background.Color}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource CogwheelButton.Border.Color}"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                <Border x:Name="border" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="Transparent">
                    <Grid>
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Control.Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                    </Trigger>

                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Content">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <Grid Width="29" Height="35" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                    <Image Source="/Resources/CogwheelRed.png" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="20" Height="20" Margin="0" Stretch="Uniform" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                                        <Image.RenderTransform>
                                            <RotateTransform Angle="0" />
                                        </Image.RenderTransform>

                                        <Image.Triggers>
                                            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Control.Loaded">
                                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                                    <Storyboard>
                                                        <DoubleAnimation AutoReverse="False"                             
                                                            Duration="0:0:3"
                                                            From="0"
                                                            RepeatBehavior="Forever"
                                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)"
                                                            To="360" />
                                                    </Storyboard>
                                                </BeginStoryboard>
                                            </EventTrigger>
                                        </Image.Triggers>
                                    </Image>

                                    <Image Source="/Resources/CogwheelRed.png" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="20" Height="20" Margin="9,15,0,0" Stretch="Uniform" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                                        <Image.RenderTransform>
                                            <RotateTransform Angle="0" />
                                        </Image.RenderTransform>
                                        
                                        
                                        <Image.Triggers>
                                            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Control.Loaded">
                                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                                    <Storyboard>
                                                        <DoubleAnimation AutoReverse="False"                             
                                                            Duration="0:0:3"
                                                            From="0"
                                                            RepeatBehavior="Forever"
                                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)"
                                                            To="-360" />
                                                    </Storyboard>
                                                </BeginStoryboard>
                                            </EventTrigger>
                                        </Image.Triggers>
                                    </Image>
                                </Grid>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>

                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Content">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <Grid Width="29" Height="35" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                    <Image Source="/Resources/CogwheelGray.png" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="20" Height="20" Margin="0" Stretch="Uniform"/>
                                    <Image Source="/Resources/CogwheelGray.png" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="20" Height="20" Margin="9,15,0,0" Stretch="Uniform" />
                                </Grid>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why this is happening is that the images in the triggers are frozen and not shared, so there will only be one instance.

Since this is a pretty static design, an alternate approach would be to replace the ContentPresenter with the actual images and then only change their sources and trigger the animations on IsChecked.

Here is the working XAML:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="CogwheelButton.Border.Color" Color="Transparent" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="CogwheelButton.Background.Color" Color="Transparent" />

<Style x:Key="CogwheelButton" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource CogwheelButton.Background.Color}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource CogwheelButton.Border.Color}" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                <Border x:Name="border"
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    BorderBrush="Transparent"
                    BorderThickness="0">
                    <Grid
                        Width="29"
                        Height="35"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <Image x:Name="Cog1"
                            Width="20"
                            Height="20"
                            Margin="0"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                            VerticalAlignment="Top"
                            RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
                            Source="/Resources/CogwheelGray.png"
                            Stretch="Uniform">
                            <Image.RenderTransform>
                                <RotateTransform Angle="0" />
                            </Image.RenderTransform>
                        </Image>
                        <Image x:Name="Cog2"
                            Width="20"
                            Height="20"
                            Margin="9,15,0,0"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                            VerticalAlignment="Top"
                            RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
                            Source="/Resources/CogwheelGray.png"
                            Stretch="Uniform">
                            <Image.RenderTransform>
                                <RotateTransform Angle="0" />
                            </Image.RenderTransform>
                        </Image>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Control.Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
                    </Trigger>

                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Cog1" Property="Source" Value="/Resources/CogwheelRed.png" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Cog2" Property="Source" Value="/Resources/CogwheelRed.png" />
                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard x:Name="CogAnimation">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation
                                        AutoReverse="False"
                                        RepeatBehavior="Forever"
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="Cog1"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)"
                                        From="0"
                                        To="360"
                                        Duration="0:0:3" />
                                    <DoubleAnimation
                                        AutoReverse="False"
                                        RepeatBehavior="Forever"
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="Cog2"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)"
                                        From="0"
                                        To="-360"
                                        Duration="0:0:3" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <Trigger.ExitActions>
                            <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="CogAnimation" />
                        </Trigger.ExitActions>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Works like a charm. I woundn't have thought to do it this way...
Thanks a lot!